# How to execute Jquery method without handler event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call a method right way on a div element based on simples if?

I have a Javascript function

```
function update() {
   if (x >= 450 || x <= 450+100) {
       $('#div').<what_goes_here>()
```

I want to animate a `<div id="section">` based on a conditional test that I am running through canvas. I don't want to run it through an event like mouseclick or keypress, just run a animate method of Jquery.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? `<what_goes_here>` can be the `animate` method.

Comment: I think I couldn't be more specific than that. Regards to your answer. It was exactly I was waiting for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the function immediately, then you have to invoke it like so:

```
(function update() {
    if (x >= 450 || x <= 450 + 100) {
        $("div").animate(); //Your action here
    }
})();
```

This could also be done anonymously if you only want to run it one time, but if you want to call it again, you can assign the name to it.  To run a one-time anonymous function, you can do this:

```
(function () {
    if (x >= 450 || x <= 450 + 100) {
        $("#section").animate(); //Your action here
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer was exactly I was waiting for. I didn't mind that I could call it without calling an event. I even didn't test!